# OperationalError at /profile/ no such table: users_profile even after I made migrations

Tags: python, django

I have the problem. When I'm trying to open a profile page to see the user's photo, but I can't, when I delete the line with user.register.photo, It works. I created a model, where there is a field that allows to users appload a photo, but when I'm trying to open "profile/" it shows this mistake. Seems like the problem is in migrations. I tried to delete migration folder, sqlite3 base and make migrations again, but it showed that "there are no changes" after I used makemigrations. It did not work for me, how can I fix this problem?

users/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

users/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Создан аккаунт {username}!')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html')
```

users/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

users/templates/users/profile.html

```
{% extends "main/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="content-section">
      <div class="media">
        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile_image.url }}">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }}</h2>
          <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Здесь будет форма -->
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

users/migrations/0001_initial.py

```
 from django.conf import settings
 from django.db import migrations, models
 import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

initial = True

dependencies = [
    migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Profile',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('image', models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')),
            ('user', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
        ],
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ran into any migration problem, removing the migration folders is not a good approach, because if you had migration files in your migration folder and already you have run the `python manage.py migrate` command, the schema that is defined in the migration files has sent to the database. also, these migration file names are entered in the django_migrations table in the database,

Imagine we have a migration folder in simple_app with these migrations files and the issue related to the last migration file:

```
first_migration.py
second_migration.py
third_migration.py
```

So what should we do if we wanted to remove the last migration file:

1. We should undo the applyment of that migration from DB by running this command:

   `python manage.py migrate simple_app second_migration`

after that you will see something like:

```
Running migrations:
    Rendering model states... DONE
    Unapplying simple_app.third_migration OK
```

this command does 2 jobs, one: undo table schema changes in the migration file, two: remove the migration file name from django_migration table)

2. We should remove third_migration.py file from the migration folder

After these steps, you can fix your model issue and after that you can run `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands to performing your changes to database again

So because you didn't follow mentioned steps, you are getting the "there are no changes" message, follow the steps, and I guess your issue will fixed`enter code here`